# How to check if a file is already opened over ssh?

Tags: nautilus, ssh, files

I have  a PC with Ubuntu server and I use it with friends to program on a project over SSH. The problem is that sometimes we have the same file opened and if somebody changes something and saves the changes, he overwrites the changes of the other programmer.
How can I check (e.g. with Nautilus) if a file is already opened by somebody else or how can I block others from opening/editing the file I'm currently working on?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
lsof | grep <part_of_filename>
```

in the console. `lsof` will give you a list of all currently open files in the system. With `grep` you can filter out lines wich contain the search term.

If `lsof` is not available on your system, you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install lsof
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Lsof is installed. Is there a possibility to implement this into the Nautilus, to see this immediately? Or to block the fies I opened? Anyway +1!

Comment: I just opened a file and did the command you gave me, but it is not displayed as open. It's just showing the DIRectories. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not an expert on nautilus, but maybe you can write a [script](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto) for that.

Comment: It probably depends on the editor, why the file is not listed as open. Maybe it opens the file, reads it into memory and then closes it again. In that case you're probably out of luck. You could try to use an editor with a locking option in that case. `vim` for example gives you a warning if you try to edit an already opened file. I'm not advocating to learn `vim` if you've never used it before, though - it has a really steep learning curve :)

Comment: You are almost certainly better off using some form of version control (subversion).

Comment: Yeah i used vim, but honestly it's a little to hard for me^^ I'm using Geany, and there is realy no possibility to block the file if I'm opening it?